# How to animate a simple shape moving vertically?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, timer

So, I have a rectangle "rectangle1", at 160,160.

I want it to move **smoothly** to cordinates 160,30, with a duration of about 1 second. (time delay)

I've figured out that some basic code to move the shape is

```
rectangle1.Location = new Point(160,30);
```

However, when I tried doing a for loop with

```
rectangle1.Location = new Point(160, rectangle1.Location.Y - 100);
```

it just moved there instantly. Which I should have expected really. Same occurred with

```
int count = 0;
while(count != 300)
{
       rectangle1.Location = new Point(160, rectangle1.Location.Y -1);
       count += 2;
}
```

So, I assume I need some sort of clock / timer loop, that moves it by `x pixels every x milliseconds`. Not sure how to do this, so help would be appreciated.

---

Also, I'm going to be animating two other rectangles horizontally, which will then move up at the same time/speed as rectangle1. I think I'll have to "delay" rectangle1's movement until they are in position, correct?

Thanks.

PS: I've googled a fair bit, but since I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for, it wasn't very fruitful.

Comment: moving the cordinates ;) up, down, left right :D with a `timer`, `sleep` or `backgroundworker` :) Or you can take a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) link too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need smooth movements, it's great to use timers, threads, backgroundworkers.

Here is what you need to do. Assuming you have the code that increment/decrement x,y points for the shape.

Steps:

- set timer interval to for e.g. 100
- set an integer int count=0;  *
- in timer_tick event do the moving work

  ```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   // no need to use your while loop anymore :))
    {       
     If(count< 300) //set to your own criteria
     {
       //e.g. myrect.location=new point(x,y);
       // rectangle1.Location = new Point(160, rectangle1.Location.Y -1);       
     }

      count += 2;
  }
  ```

Comment: Perfect. Combined this with http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f and got the solution.